# Using /etc/auto.master.d together with wildcard `*` to mount `/home`

Tags: linux, automounting, autofs

My problem is similar to that described in [Need example use of autofs.master.d/](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/375516/320598):

I wanted to mount individual users' home directories to `/home/*user*` using both, `*` wildcard and directory `/etc/auto.master.d` in SLES15 SP4, but when I try to mount some directory via `ls -l /home/*user*`, nothing happens (even when having activated automount debugging, I see no log messages related to my attempt to mount).

I've created an `/etc/auto.master.d/homes`, containing `/home /etc/auto.homes`, and the latter file itself contains `* -bg,rw,hard,intr,nfsvers=3 nfs.server.org:/exports/home/&`.

I can test-mount my test-user's home directory manually without a problem, however.

I'm not quite sure I understood how to use `/etc/auto.master.d` correctly, so an answer explaining my error could also point me in the right direction.

Comment: Auto.master gives the global parameters. You probably want auto.net for user-named NFS mounts. Can't write an example now until Monday. Ping if you need one still

Comment: @roaima `/etc/auto.net` is a *program map*, and `/etc/auto.net` will mount everything a specific host will export. Not what I wanted to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the "solution", but not the reason:

When replacing `+dir:/etc/auto.master.d` (that should include `/etc/auto.master.d/homes`) with `/home /etc/auto.homes`, then it (`/etc/auto.homes` mounting directories in `/home`) works.

However the comment in `auto.master` says:

```text
# Include /etc/auto.master.d/*.autofs
# The included files must conform to the format of this file.
#
#+dir:/etc/auto.master.d
```

So I assumed that including a file is the same as including the content of the corresponding file literally.
Obviously not true.

### Update

Eventually I found it in "auto.master(5)" for "map type" `dir`:

> (...) The name of file to be included must be ended with ".autofs". (...)

### Final Remark

In general reading before typing helps:
The comment in the file says: "*Include /etc/auto.master.d/*.autofs*"

I noticed it only *after* having found the solution.
Maybe it's time to start the weekend now...